# Uploading existing shapefile from geoserver to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, geoserver, pgadmin-4

Few weeks back, I upload lots and lots of data (shapefile) directly to the geoserver. Now, I just installed postgresql. How can I link the existing uploaded files in geoserver (shapefiles) to postgres using pgAdmin 4.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Shapefiles and PostgreSQL are two different storage backends. You'll need to find some tool that does the conversion for you.

Note: Most conversion tools will expect you to be using the PostGIS extensions to PostgreSQL.


Also, you would probably have better luck over at the GIS Stack Exchange: https://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's okay. I have already solve the problem. What I did was, after connecting the geoserver and postgresql, I republish all the data. Thank you for the reply.